# How to "flatten" JSON representation of objects using circe i.e., from case class to its string representation?

Tags: scala, circe

I have a custom `Date` class that we use internally:

```
case class Date(month: Int, day: Int, year: Year)
```

And use this as so:

```
case class Person(dateOfBirth: Date)
```

However, when I generate the Json  for `Person(Date(12, 20, 1990))` I get something like:

```
{
 "dateOfBirth": {
  "month": 12,
  "day": 20,
  "year": 1990
 }
}
```

What I'd like to get is something like this:

```
{ "dateOfBirth": "12-20-2990" } // or any custom format
```

Is it possible to "flatten" custom case classes so that they're just treated like a value instead of being expanded out? I've tried something like this and it leads to a `StackOverflowError`:

```
  implicit val dateEncoder: Encoder[Date] = (date: Date) => {
    Json.fromString(s"${date.month}-${date.dayOfMonth}-${date.year}")
  }
```

**UPDATE**: This error seems unrelated to the encoder - it just happens to get triggered when this encoder is added but not otherwise forcing me to conclude that this is not the right way of encoding. I've accepted the answer since it does correctly answer the "asked" question.

Here's the encoder that "fails" after the Date one is added in:

```
  implicit val myEncoder: Encoder[Vector[MyCaseClass]] = (my: Vector[MyCaseClass]) => {
    if (my.nonEmpty) my.asJson else Json.Null
  }
```

I could encode this as an `Option[Vector[MyCaseClass]]` but I was experimenting with directly encoding a Vector to see what happens...

Comment: What are your current definitions for the encoders of `Date` and `Person`? Even if you are importing the generic autoderived ones, please include that in the question.

Comment: About your update: you really don't ever want to use the encoder for a type `A` inside the implicit definition of a `Encoder[A]`—it will resolve itself and you'll get an SO.

Comment: Call `Decoder.decodeVector` explicitly if you have to, but defining a custom instance for `Vector[Whatever]` isn't really best practice. Anyway this is getting pretty far from the original question, which has a correct answer below.

Comment: @TravisBrown - Yes. Added it as a separate Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029870/how-to-skip-over-empty-arrays-in-the-generated-json-with-circe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write an encoder/decoder for any type manually. It seems you need a new implementation for `Date`:

```scala
object Date {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Date] = (date: Date) =>
    Json.fromString(s"${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}")
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Date] = ??? // if you need this
}
```

Comment: I did try this. And circe crapped out! The entire json hierarchy failed when I did this. Hence the question.

Comment: Can you please update your question with how it failed?

Comment: This is IMO the right approach. If it fails, something else is probably wrong. Did you define the implicit encoders in the companion object? I've never had any problem with circe using it this way.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'd do.

Comment: @Koterpillar @TravisBrown - Seems there's an intermittent `StackoverflowError` that somehow gets triggered by adding the above encoder. It doesn't seem related but it was sorta _causal_ causing me to incorrectly conclude that the encoding strategy is incorrect. I'm digging further to find out _why_ there's an SO error - it's an encoder for a `Vector[MyCaseClass]` and I try to make it `Json.Null` if it's an empty Vector. Something must be going in an infinite recursion to make this happen...