# How to skip over empty arrays in the generated Json with Circe?

Tags: scala, circe

```
//Domain

case class Item(price: Int)
case class Data(name: String, items: Vector[Item])

Data("stackoverflow", Vector(Item(100))).asJson

//ouput:

{
 "name": "stackoverflow",
 "items": [
  {
    "price": 100
  }
 ]
}

// With Empty items:
Data("stackoverflow", Vector()).asJson

// expected output:
{
 "name": "stackoverflow",
 "items": null // Can be removed with Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true)
}
```

I tried doing something like:

```
  implicit val itemsEncoder: Encoder[Vector[Item]] = (items: Vector[Item]) => {
    if (items.nonEmpty) items.asJson else Json.Null
  }
```

And this results in a `StackoverflowError`.

**Goal**: If there are no elements in the array, there shouldn't be any empty array `"items": []` in the output. How can I achieve this?

A *possible alternative* is to encode `Option[Vector[Item]]` like so:

```
implicit val optionalVector: Encoder[Option[Vector[Item]]] = {
 case Some(v) =>
  if(v.isEmpty) Json.Null else v.asJson
 case None => Json.Null
}
```

I don't like this solution since it forces an `Option` type on the domain objects just to generate the Json.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead,

```
  implicit val itemsEncoder: Encoder[Vector[Item]] = (items: Vector[Item]) => {
    if (items.nonEmpty) items.asJson(Encoder.encodeVector) else Json.Null
  }
```

where you are telling it to use the standard `Vector` encoder instead of `itemsEncoder` again.

Comment: I would've _never_ guessed that...interesting. I tried it and it doesn't throw `SO` so maybe it does work :)

Comment: @PhD yeah, when you call `.asJson` it goes looking for the appropriate `Encoder`, and since `items` is a `Vector[Item]` it's like "oh great I have one right here!"... ad infinitum...